# Windows 10 Blue Screen Error (SYSTEM SERVICE EXCEPTION)

Tags: windows, bsod

I open my pc failed, it shows blue scree with error (SYSTEM SERVICE EXCEPTION), than I start it for safe mode and get the dump file, open in another pc.
This is my analyze result by windbg in below.
Please help me.
Thanks.

```
3: kd> !analyze -v
*******************************************************************************
*                                                                             *
*                        Bugcheck Analysis                                    *
*                                                                             *
*******************************************************************************

SYSTEM_SERVICE_EXCEPTION (3b)
An exception happened while executing a system service routine.
Arguments:
Arg1: 00000000c0000005, Exception code that caused the bugcheck
Arg2: 0000000000000000, Address of the instruction which caused the bugcheck
Arg3: ffffd0002048c840, Address of the context record for the exception that caused the bugcheck
Arg4: 0000000000000000, zero.

Debugging Details:
------------------


DUMP_CLASS: 1

DUMP_QUALIFIER: 400

BUILD_VERSION_STRING:  10586.420.amd64fre.th2_release_sec.160527-1834

SYSTEM_MANUFACTURER:  Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd.

SYSTEM_PRODUCT_NAME:  B85M-DS3H

SYSTEM_SKU:  To be filled by O.E.M.

SYSTEM_VERSION:  To be filled by O.E.M.

BIOS_VENDOR:  American Megatrends Inc.

BIOS_VERSION:  FD

BIOS_DATE:  06/19/2014

BASEBOARD_MANUFACTURER:  Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd.

BASEBOARD_PRODUCT:  B85M-DS3H

BASEBOARD_VERSION:  x.x

DUMP_TYPE:  2

BUGCHECK_P1: c0000005

BUGCHECK_P2: 0

BUGCHECK_P3: ffffd0002048c840

BUGCHECK_P4: 0

EXCEPTION_CODE: (NTSTATUS) 0xc0000005 - 0x%p

FAULTING_IP: 
+0
00000000`00000000 ??              ???

CONTEXT:  ffffd0002048c840 -- (.cxr 0xffffd0002048c840)
rax=0000000000000000 rbx=ffffe001fa4c4a58 rcx=ffffe001fa4c4a58
rdx=ffffd0002048d2c0 rsi=ffffe001fa4c4af8 rdi=ffffe001fa4c4980
rip=0000000000000000 rsp=ffffd0002048d268 rbp=ffffe001fa41bbe0
 r8=0000000000000000  r9=0000000000000000 r10=fffff8006dbf0000
r11=0000000000000001 r12=0000000000000000 r13=ffffe001fa41be10
r14=0000000000000000 r15=0000000000000000
iopl=0         nv up ei pl zr na po nc
cs=0010  ss=0018  ds=002b  es=002b  fs=0053  gs=002b             efl=00010246
00000000`00000000 ??              ???
Resetting default scope

CPU_COUNT: 4

CPU_MHZ: cdc

CPU_VENDOR:  GenuineIntel

CPU_FAMILY: 6

CPU_MODEL: 3c

CPU_STEPPING: 3

CPU_MICROCODE: 6,3c,3,0 (F,M,S,R)  SIG: 1E'00000000 (cache) 1E'00000000 (init)

CUSTOMER_CRASH_COUNT:  1

DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID:  WIN8_DRIVER_FAULT

BUGCHECK_STR:  0x3B

PROCESS_NAME:  svchost.exe

CURRENT_IRQL:  0

ANALYSIS_SESSION_HOST:  DESKTOP-BHLSA7K

ANALYSIS_SESSION_TIME:  06-23-2016 11:27:37.0156

ANALYSIS_VERSION: 10.0.10586.567 amd64fre

LAST_CONTROL_TRANSFER:  from fffff8006dbf62db to 0000000000000000

IP_IN_FREE_BLOCK: 0

STACK_TEXT:  
ffffd000`2048d268 fffff800`6dbf62db : ffffe001`fa4c4980 ffffe001`fa4c4c78 00000000`00000040 fffff800`00000000 : 0x0
ffffd000`2048d270 fffff800`6dbf5cb6 : ffffe001`fa4c4900 00000000`00000000 00000000`c0000016 00000000`00000000 : FLTMGR!FltpPerformPostCallbacks+0x2ab
ffffd000`2048d340 fffff800`6dbf7928 : ffffe001`fa4c4998 ffffe001`fa4c4980 ffffe001`fa3d5010 ffffe001`fa3d5440 : FLTMGR!FltpPassThroughCompletionWorker+0x76
ffffd000`2048d380 fffff800`6dc262d7 : 00000000`00000000 ffffe001`fa12f4f0 ffffd001`00000000 00000000`00000801 : FLTMGR!FltpLegacyProcessingAfterPreCallbacksCompleted+0x238
ffffd000`2048d410 fffff800`58016d38 : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000005 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000189 : FLTMGR!FltpCreate+0x347
ffffd000`2048d4c0 fffff800`5800d6a6 : ffffc001`6b6273b8 ffffc001`6b6273b8 ffffd000`2048d790 ffffe001`f8212c50 : nt!IopParseDevice+0x7c8
ffffd000`2048d690 fffff800`5800c0ac : ffffe001`fa3f4b01 ffffd000`2048d8a0 00ffffe0`00000040 ffffe001`f418af20 : nt!ObpLookupObjectName+0x776
ffffd000`2048d830 fffff800`5803dd48 : ffffe001`00000001 ffffe001`fa410b10 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : nt!ObOpenObjectByNameEx+0x1ec
ffffd000`2048d950 fffff800`5803d8a9 : 000000e0`84ffec38 fffff800`57f0bf80 000000e0`84ffecb0 000000e0`84ffec50 : nt!IopCreateFile+0x3d8
ffffd000`2048da00 fffff800`57d560a3 : ffffc001`6d3211c0 fffff800`57fc7ced 000000e0`84ffed48 ffffe001`00000028 : nt!NtCreateFile+0x79
ffffd000`2048da90 00007ff9`ab8a5b84 : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : nt!KiSystemServiceCopyEnd+0x13
000000e0`84ffebb8 00000000`00000000 : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : 0x00007ff9`ab8a5b84


THREAD_SHA1_HASH_MOD_FUNC:  d3c9c5375a95d2e8878fb116dc3127eb827d454f

THREAD_SHA1_HASH_MOD_FUNC_OFFSET:  1537388f81059bbcc20a83649db835e96da03547

THREAD_SHA1_HASH_MOD:  f4143f7434a8c25979619eb6afebf44f2b1f5926

FOLLOWUP_IP: 
FLTMGR!FltpPerformPostCallbacks+2ab
fffff800`6dbf62db 8bc8            mov     ecx,eax

FAULT_INSTR_CODE:  f983c88b

SYMBOL_STACK_INDEX:  1

SYMBOL_NAME:  FLTMGR!FltpPerformPostCallbacks+2ab

FOLLOWUP_NAME:  MachineOwner

MODULE_NAME: FLTMGR

IMAGE_NAME:  FLTMGR.SYS

DEBUG_FLR_IMAGE_TIMESTAMP:  5632d176

IMAGE_VERSION:  10.0.10586.0

STACK_COMMAND:  .cxr 0xffffd0002048c840 ; kb

BUCKET_ID_FUNC_OFFSET:  2ab

FAILURE_BUCKET_ID:  0x3B_FLTMGR!FltpPerformPostCallbacks

BUCKET_ID:  0x3B_FLTMGR!FltpPerformPostCallbacks

PRIMARY_PROBLEM_CLASS:  0x3B_FLTMGR!FltpPerformPostCallbacks

TARGET_TIME:  2016-06-23T03:03:52.000Z

OSBUILD:  10586

OSSERVICEPACK:  0

SERVICEPACK_NUMBER: 0

OS_REVISION: 0

SUITE_MASK:  272

PRODUCT_TYPE:  1

OSPLATFORM_TYPE:  x64

OSNAME:  Windows 10

OSEDITION:  Windows 10 WinNt TerminalServer SingleUserTS

OS_LOCALE:  

USER_LCID:  0

OSBUILD_TIMESTAMP:  2016-05-28 11:59:07

BUILDDATESTAMP_STR:  160527-1834

BUILDLAB_STR:  th2_release_sec

BUILDOSVER_STR:  10.0.10586.420.amd64fre.th2_release_sec.160527-1834

ANALYSIS_SESSION_ELAPSED_TIME: 5ac3

ANALYSIS_SOURCE:  KM

FAILURE_ID_HASH_STRING:  km:0x3b_fltmgr!fltpperformpostcallbacks

FAILURE_ID_HASH:  {4167dd89-437f-47a2-6c22-0b8fb315a500}

Followup:     MachineOwner
---------
```

Comment: run .cxr 0xffffd0002048c840 ; kb and look or more details

Comment: The presence of fltmgr (filter manager) shows that your failure occurred because of a bug in a file system filter or minifilter driver. These are usually parts of add-on file cacheing packages (completely unnecessary) and anti-malware products (sadly, not unnecessary). What add-on software is on the machine?

Comment: any update? have you run the commands that I posted? Do you see more details?

Answer (score -1):

A lot of the time this is caused by the video driver. Try either rolling back your video card driver or getting a copy of the video driver from either Intel if you are using your on board graphics or from your video card manufacture if you are not using the on board graphics.

Here is a link to where you can find drivers if you are using on board graphics. https://downloadcenter.intel.com/

If the above doesn't work try doing a memory test follow the instructions from here. http://www.troubleshootwindows.com/windows-vista/windows-memory-diagnostic-test-your-computer-ram-for-errors/ Skip down to the part where it says "If you are unable to boot into Windows".

Source:
Past experience and Microsoft

http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_vista-performance/system-service-exception-where-to-start/4355c32a-6899-45e8-8c29-b83341f361c4?auth=1